# Does Prometheus actually *store* the scrape timestamp for a sample?

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to get the actual timestamp that a given metric was scraped at from Prometheus.

Does Prometheus store this information at all? I can't seem to find clear info on that.

If I run the query

```
timestamp(label_replace({__name__=~"someprefix.+"},"__tmp_name", "$0", "__name__", ".*"))
```

where `someprefix` matches two or more metrics that have more than one source instance, I the value always seems to match the timestamp I specify as the target in in the query, right down to the millisecond. I'd expect timestamps to be staggered based on scrape time.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out while posting the question.

The `label_replace` generates a synthetic series, and the timestamp values of the synthetic series is the timestamp of its evaluation. It doesn't retain the original timestamps of the input timeseries.

```
timestamp(someprefix_exact_name)
```

will show scrape timestamps varying as expected.

I would be interested to know if there's a way to preserve the original scrape timestamp when munging timeseries, e.g. inject it into a synthetic label.